# How can I disallow the user to go to the register page when he is already logged in? Django 2.1.2

Tags: django, authentication, registration

I made an admin panel in django. Which consists of login registration and dashboard for admin but i am facing a problem that:

If suppose a user is logged in to the system, and then the user goes to the url and go to register page using the url for ex. localhost/register when he is already logged in and no need of going to register page to register another user account. I don,t want this to happen.

How can I disallow the user to go to the register page when he is already logged in. How can we resolve this issue? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
def register(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
       return redirect('/')  # or reverse('home_url_name')
   else:
       ....
```

#### Update from comments:

You need to override `LoginView` for adding this functionality in login as well, for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

class CustomLoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       if request.user.is_authenticated:
           return redirect('/')
       return super(CustomLogin, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)


# URL
path('accounts/login/', CustomLoginView.as_view()),
```

Comment: It worked!! thanks alot. How can we do the same thing for login, as i am using inbuilt django login method?

Comment: Adding to @ruddra answer, (If you want a front end solution) You can add `is_authenticated` in your html and let them go to that page and show a message something like `log out to add a new user` with your signup link.